# How do I make a Text sticky - Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, sticky

I designed a screen in Compose and there is a component called FreePremiumText on my screen, there are two Text in this component. I want these texts to be sticky, so even if the user scrolls the screen, they will always remain fixed. However, I didn't know how to do this in my code. Can you give a suggestion
? How can I do that. By the way, the location of the text will not change, it will only be sticky.

**hear is my code**:

```
 Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            ExitButton(
                navHostController = navHostController,
                route = DASHBOARD_ROUTE
            )
        },
    ) {

        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .weight(1f)
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                if (state.isLoading) {
                    CenterAlignLoadingAnimation()
                } else {
                    HeaderSection(
                        title = stringResource(id = R.string.xxx),
                        titleContent = stringResource(id = R.string.xxx),
                        titleStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp))
                    state.registerPaymentResponse?.let {
                        if (it.paymentItems.isNotEmpty()) {
                            Row(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .padding(10.dp),
                                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
                            ) {
                                it.paymentItems.forEachIndexed { index, paymentItem ->

                                    TextBoxContainer(
                                        isClick = index == selectedPaymentIndex,
                                        index = index,
                                        content1 = "${paymentItem.period} ${paymentItem.periodName}",
                                        content2 = "${paymentItem.perMonthPrice} / ${paymentItem.periodName}",
                                        content3 = "${paymentItem.price} ${stringResource(id = R.string.x)}",
                                        suggested = paymentItem.suggested,
                                        cardLabelText = stringResource(id = R.string.populer),
                                        onClick = { _index ->
                                            selectedPaymentIndex = _index
                                        }
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
                    Text(
                        text = "xxx",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle2.copy(fontWeight = FontWeight.W900)
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))

                    FreePremiumText() //  <--- HEAR IS MY FreePremiumText component
                    state.registerPaymentResponse?.let {
                        if (it.featureItems.isNotEmpty()) {
                            it.featureItems.forEachIndexed { index, featureItem ->
                                FeatureItem(
                                    title = featureItem.title,
                                    premiumKeyStatus = featureItem.premiumKeyStatus,
                                    freeKeyStatus = featureItem.freeKeyStatus
                                )
                            }
                            CustomDivider(startPadding = 15.dp, endPadding = 15.dp)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(25.dp))
                    RemindLaterText(
                        onClick = {

                        },
                        text = stringResource(id = R.string.remindlater)
                    )
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
                DYTLoginAndContinueButton(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(16.dp),
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.x),
                    navController = navHostController,
                    route = null,
                    enabled = true
                ) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**FreePremiumText.kt**

```
@Composable
fun FreePremiumText() {


    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
   
    val weight = if(screenHeight > 600.dp) 1.5f else 1f

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(end = 10.dp),
    ) {

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(weight)
        ) {
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(end = 0.dp)
                .weight(1f)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Free",
                fontSize = 15.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 15.dp)
            )
            Text(text = "Premium", fontSize = 15.sp)
        }

    }

}
```